# Flexbox, boxes inside boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am busy with a very simple thing of CSS. Let´s say I have four squares and inside each another square. I want my layout to look something like this:

[image: Layout I am looking for]

But it looks like this:

[image: My layout]

But I can't get it right. The four squares are grouped in one element and display is set to inline-block. I want to move the small boxes inside their parents and I think I should do it with "display: flex" and "justify-content: flex-end" for example as in the code below. My code in HTML and CSS look like this.

```css
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: honeydew;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 100%;

}

.big {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
}

.small {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
}

#small-1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#small-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}


#small-3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
}


#small-4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: grey">
            <div class="small" id="small-1" style="background-color:orange"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: black">
            <div class="small" id="small-2" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: blue">
            <div class="small" id="small-3" style="background-color: green"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: purple">
            <div class="small" id="small-4" style="background-color: pink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me with this? It seems pretty obvious and basic, but somehow doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edits**:

```
div.block:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {
  align-items: start; // to vertically align to start
}
div.block:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: start;// to horizontally align to start
  align-items: start; // to vertically align to start
}
div.block:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: start; // to horizontally align to start
}
body{
  display:flex;
}
```

### **justify-content:**

---

> **`start`**: items are packed toward the **start** of the `writing-mode` direction.**`end`**: items are packed toward the **end** of the writing-mode direction.

### **align-items:**

---

> **`flex-start / start / self-start`**: items are placed at the **start** of the cross axis. The difference between these is subtle, and is about respecting the flex-direction rules or the writing-mode rules.
> **`flex-end / end / self-end`**: items are placed at the **end** of the cross axis. The difference again is subtle and is about respecting flex-direction rules vs. writing-mode rules.

## [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

### **[`CodePen Demo`](https://codepen.io/CodingDoubts/pen/ExKqxoE)**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: honeydew;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;

}

.big {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.small {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
div.block:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {
  align-items: start; 
}
div.block:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start; 
}
div.block:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: start; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: grey">
            <div class="small" id="small-1" style="background-color:orange"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: black">
            <div class="small" id="small-2" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: blue">
            <div class="small" id="small-3" style="background-color: green"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="big" style="background-color: purple">
            <div class="small" id="small-4" style="background-color: pink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content` and `align-items` should be placed on the container level, so the `#small`'s don't have to be that props, but `.big`.

I create a pen as example:
https://codepen.io/alecell-the-lessful/pen/qBZeBEx

[EDIT]
I just realise that I don't answer your question, and maybe that link helps you: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties)

The point is that you should use `item level` selectors such as `align-self` and `margin` to reach the desired behavior.

As above I provide a pen to example: https://codepen.io/alecell-the-lessful/pen/zYqgYvd